# php array - get first row of ETime and next row of STime

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here's my php array with row start and end times

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [STime] => 09:00:00
            [ETime] => 10:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [STime] => 10:15:00
            [ETime] => 11:15:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [STime] => 11:30:00
            [ETime] => 12:15:00
        )

)
```

How can i format my array to get first row of ETime and next row of STime. Result should be an array of

> Array
>       (
>           [0] => Array
>               (
>                   [0] => 10:00:00
>                   [1] => 10:15:00
>               )
>
> ```
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>           [0] => 11:15:00
>             [1] => 11:30:00
>         ) 
>
>     [2] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 12:15:00
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value){
  if (isset($array1[$key+1]['STime'])){
    $array2[] = array($value['ETime'],$array1[$key+1]['STime']);
  }
  else{
    $array2[] = array($value['ETime']);
  }
}
```